# qt: pyqt: QTreeView internal drag and drop almost working... dragged item disappears

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt, qtreeview

I *almost* have a completely working drag and drop re-order within a QTreeView.  Everything seems to be ok except the dropped object never appears (though I can reference it numerous different ways that proves to me that it actually exists where it should be).  If anyone has a moment and could run the following code and let me know what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it.  I have been banging my head against this process for over a week now:

You should be able to just copy and run the following code (I have a bunch of print statements in it that *seem* to indicate that everything is working correctly but obviously something is off):

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore



################################################################################
class Branch(object):
    """
    Basic branch/leaf node.
    """

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, name, value, parent=None):
        """
        Constructor.
        """
        super(Branch, self).__init__()

        #name and parent are both to be stored directly as variables
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = value

        #store sub-objects (usually other branches)
        self.objD = dict()
        self.nameL = list()


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_name(self):
        """
        Getter.
        """
        return self.name


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_parent(self):
        """
        Returns the parent of this object.
        """
        return self.parent


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def set_value(self, value):
        """
        Generic setter for all settings.
        """
        self.value = value


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_value(self):
        """
        Generic getter for all settings. Returns the display value
        """
        return self.value


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_child_obj(self, obj, row=None):
        """
        Adds the param object to the dict and list.
        """
        self.objD[obj.get_name()] = obj
        if row == None:
            self.nameL.append(obj.get_name())
        else:
            self.nameL.insert(row, obj.get_name())

        print "JUST ADDED CHILD AT ROW:", self.nameL.index(obj.get_name())


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def remove_child_at_row(self, row):
        """
        Removes the param object from the dict and list.
        """
        childName = self.nameL[row]
        del(self.nameL[row])
        del(self.objD[childName])


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_child_count(self):
        """
        Returns the number of children in this branch.
        """
        return len(self.nameL)


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_child_list(self):
        """
        Returns a list of the visible children names.
        """
        return self.nameL


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_child_at_row(self, row):
        """
        Returns a specific child object based on its ordinal (only consider
        visible children).
        """
        childName = self.nameL[row]
        return self.objD[childName]


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_child_by_name(self, childName):
        """
        Returns a specific child object based on its name.
        """
        return self.objD[childName]


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_index(self):
        """
        Returns this object's index position with regard to its siblings.
        """
        siblingsL = self.parent.get_child_list()
        return siblingsL.index(self.get_name())




################################################################################
class MyTreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):
    """
    Overrides the QTreeView to handle keypress events.
    """

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        """
        Constructor for the TreeView class.
        """
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setModel(model)




################################################################################
class MyTreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):

    """
    My tree view data model
    """

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, root):
        """
        Constructor for the TreeModel class
        """
        super(MyTreeModel, self).__init__()
        self.root = root
        self.fontSize = 8
        self.selection = None


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        """
        Returns the number of columns in the treeview. 
        """
        return 1


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        """
        Returns the number of children of the current index obj.
        """
        if index.column() > 0:
            return 0
        if not index.isValid():
            item = self.root
        else:
            item = index.internalPointer()
        if item:
            return item.get_child_count()
        return 0


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        """
        Returns a QModelIndex item for the current row, column, and parent.
        """
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.root
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        childItem = parentItem.get_child_at_row(row)
        if childItem:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def parent(self, index):
        """
        Returns a QModelIndex item for the parent of the given index.
        """
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        childItem = index.internalPointer()
        if not childItem:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        parentItem = childItem.get_parent()

        if parentItem == self.root:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parentItem.get_index(), 0, parentItem)


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        """
        Returns the text or formatting for a particular cell, depending on the 
        role supplied.
        """
        #invalid indexes return invalid results
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        #access the underlying referenced object
        item = index.internalPointer()

        #edit role displays the raw values
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return item.get_value()

        #return the data to display
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return item.get_value()

        return QtCore.QVariant()


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def headerData(self, index, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        """
        Returns the text for the horizontal headers (parameter names)
        """

        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                alignment = int(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
                return QtCore.QVariant(alignment)
            alignment = int(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
            return QtCore.QVariant(alignment)

        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if int(index) == 0:
                return "Name"


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def supportedDropActions(self): 
        """
        We allow re-ordering. 
        """
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction         


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def flags(self, index):
        """
        Returns whether or not the current item is editable/selectable/etc. 
        """

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

        #by default, you can't do anything
        enabled = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        selectable = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        editable = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        draggable = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled
        droppable = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled

        #return our flags.
        return enabled | selectable| editable| draggable| droppable 


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        """
        Sets the data. 
        """
        #convert the value into a string
        if value:
            item = index.internalPointer()
            item.set_value(value)                

            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), 
                                     index, index)
        return True


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def supportedDropActions(self): 
        """
        Only allow moves
        """
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction 


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def mimeTypes(self):
        """
        Only accept the internal custom drop type which is plain text
        """
        types = QtCore.QStringList() 
        types.append('text/plain') 
        return types 


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def mimeData(self, index): 
        """
        Wrap the index up as a list of rows and columns of each 
        parent/grandparent/etc
        """
        rc = ""
        theIndex = index[0] #<- for testing purposes we only deal with 1st item
        while theIndex.isValid():
            rc = rc + str(theIndex.row()) + ";" + str(theIndex.column())
            theIndex = self.parent(theIndex)
            if theIndex.isValid():
                rc = rc + ","
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setText(rc)
        return mimeData


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parentIndex):
        """
        Extract the whole ancestor list of rows and columns and rebuild the 
        index item that was originally dragged
        """
        if action == QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction: 
            return True 

        if data.hasText():
            ancestorL = str(data.text()).split(",")
            ancestorL.reverse() #<- stored from the child up, we read from ancestor down
            pIndex = QtCore.QModelIndex()
            for ancestor in ancestorL:
                srcRow = int(ancestor.split(";")[0])
                srcCol = int(ancestor.split(";")[1])
                itemIndex = self.index(srcRow, srcCol, pIndex)
                pIndex = itemIndex

        item = itemIndex.internalPointer()
        parent = parentIndex.internalPointer()

        #modify the row if it is -1 (we want to append to the end of the list)
        if row == -1:
            row = parent.get_child_count()

        self.beginInsertRows(parentIndex, row-1, row)
        print "------------------"
        parentIndex.internalPointer().add_child_obj(item)
        print "------------------"
        self.endInsertRows()
        print "sanity check:"
        print "dragged Node", item.get_name()
        print "parent Node", parent.get_name()
        print "inserted at row",row
        print "inserted Node:",parent.get_child_at_row(row).get_name()
        print row, column
        print "from index():",self.index(row, 0, parentIndex).internalPointer().get_name()
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), 
                                self.index(row, 0, parentIndex), 
                                self.index(row, 0, parentIndex)) 
        return True 


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def insertRow(self, row, parent): 
        print "insertRow"
        return self.insertRows(row, 1, parent) 


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def insertRows(self, row, count, parent): 
        print "insertRows"
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, row, (row + (count - 1))) 
        self.endInsertRows() 
        return True 


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def removeRow(self, row, parentIndex): 
        print "removeRow"
        return self.removeRows(row, 1, parentIndex) 


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def removeRows(self, row, count, parentIndex): 
        self.beginRemoveRows(parentIndex, row, row) 
        print "about to remove child at row:",row
        print "which is under the parent named:",parentIndex.internalPointer().get_name()
        print "and whose own name is:",parentIndex.internalPointer().get_child_at_row(row).get_name()
        parentIndex.internalPointer().remove_child_at_row(row)
        self.endRemoveRows() 
        return True 









class Ui_MainWindow(object): 

    def printChildren(self, item):
        print item.name
        for child in item.get_child_list():
            self.printChildren(item.get_child_by_name(child))

    def printit(self):
        self.printChildren(self.root)


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): 

        root = Branch("root", "root", QtCore.QVariant)

        item1 = Branch("ITEM1","ITEM1",root)
        item2 = Branch("ITEM2","ITEM2",root)
        item3 = Branch("ITEM3","ITEM3",root)
        root.add_child_obj(item1)
        root.add_child_obj(item2)
        root.add_child_obj(item3)

        item1a = Branch("thinga","thinga",item1)
        item1b = Branch("thingb","thingb",item1)
        item1.add_child_obj(item1a)
        item1.add_child_obj(item1b)

        item2a = Branch("thingc","thingc",item2)
        item2b = Branch("thingd","thingd",item2)
        item2.add_child_obj(item2a)
        item2.add_child_obj(item2b)

        item3a = Branch("thinge","thinge",item3)
        item3b = Branch("thingf","thingf",item3)
        item3.add_child_obj(item3a)
        item3.add_child_obj(item3b)


        item1a1 = Branch("___A","___A",item1a)
        item1a2 = Branch("___B","___B",item1a)
        item1a.add_child_obj(item1a1)
        item1a.add_child_obj(item1a2)

        item1b1 = Branch("___C","___C",item1b)
        item1b2 = Branch("___D","___D",item1b)
        item1b.add_child_obj(item1b1)
        item1b.add_child_obj(item1b2)

        item2a1 = Branch("___E","___E",item2a)
        item2a2 = Branch("___F","___F",item2a)
        item2a.add_child_obj(item2a1)
        item2a.add_child_obj(item2a2)

        item2b1 = Branch("___G","___G",item2b)
        item2b2 = Branch("___H","___H",item2b)
        item2b.add_child_obj(item2b1)
        item2b.add_child_obj(item2b2)

        item3a1 = Branch("___J","___J",item3a)
        item3a2 = Branch("___K","___K",item3a)
        item3a.add_child_obj(item3a1)
        item3a.add_child_obj(item3a2)

        item3b1 = Branch("___L","___L",item3b)
        item3b2 = Branch("___M","___M",item3b)
        item3b.add_child_obj(item3b1)
        item3b.add_child_obj(item3b2)

        self.root = root

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow") 
        MainWindow.resize(600, 400) 
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow) 
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget") 
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout") 
        self.myModel = MyTreeModel(root) 
        self.treeView = MyTreeView(self.myModel, self.centralwidget) 
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView") 
        self.treeView.dragEnabled()
        self.treeView.acceptDrops()
        self.treeView.showDropIndicator()
        self.treeView.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove) 
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.treeView) 
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('print', MainWindow)
        MainWindow.connect(self.btn, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.printit)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn) 

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow) 
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 22)) 
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar") 
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar) 
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow) 
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar") 
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar) 

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow) 
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow) 









    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)) 


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow() 
    ui = Ui_MainWindow() 
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow) 
    MainWindow.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't solve all the problems, but changing dropMimeData() to the following will at least allow moving leaf items.

```
    self.beginInsertRows(parentIndex, row, row)
    parentIndex.internalPointer().add_child_obj(Branch(item.get_name(), item.get_value(), parent), row)
    self.endInsertRows()
```

A drag-drop operation is effectively two steps, an insert (done in dropMimeData) and a remove (done automatically by the Move drag operation). The changes above insert a new item rather than trying to insert an item which is already in the model and which will be removed from the old location after the insert occurs.

Comment: baysmith, thank you so much. That fixed it! I think it makes sense to me now... when I re-parent the object the QTreeView now has two indexes pointing at the same object. Then when it deletes the "old" one, it is somehow removing all references to that object (which is what you just said in your post). Question: you said it doesn't solve all the problems. Do you see others? I'm very new to this and eager to learn.  Thanks again! This was driving me crazy.

Comment: If a item with children is moved, the children are lost because the dropMimeData only copies the dragged items name and value. It should probably also move the children.

Comment: Also, the add_child_obj function doesn't update the parent reference of the child object.
The supportedDropActions function is defined twice.
The insertRow and removeRow functions are not virtual on QAbstractItemModel and therefore should probably not be overridden in the custom model.

Comment: baysmith. This is amazing. Thank you so much for your help. It really helps me wrap my head around the whole process. I already fixed the lost children issue, but had not even considered the other issues.  Thanks again.